# What reason have the designers said for why they spelled "Rötschreck" with an Umlaut?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, terminology, designer-reasons

In German language the word *rot* (meaning "Red") is spelled without an Umlaut, so would the word *Rotschreck* be if composed in German, meaning "red fear", composed of *rot* and *der Schreck*, "fear".

1. Why is Rötschreck spelled as it is then? It is clear that it breaks the rules of word composition in German, why did the developers make it this way?
2. How am I supposed to actually *read* it? In Russia we read it as if it was spelled properly, without the Umlaut, but I doubt if it was the intended way.

*To clarify:* This question is **not** looking for a German language analysis of the usage of the Umlaut. It **is** looking for a statement *from the designers* about why the Umlaut was used.

Comment: Many answers have been deleted on this question. Yes, maybe the umlaut is just to be cool.  Maybe it’s an error.  We can all guess that. The only way to answer that is with designer commentary or other sourcing that moves it from a guess to an actual reason. Answers without that will be downvoted and then deleted.

Comment: Since "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions" has been demonstrated by the *many* deleted opionion answers, I've closed this. The usual five voters who want to see this keep going can overturn that, of course.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie May I please ask for the number of deleted answers?

Comment: Eight. Over the course of exactly a year (an average of 1 answer per 6–7 weeks), that's a persistent stream of opinion.